# Add arguments to block via layout update

Tags: magento2, layout

In the catalog_product_view.xml ofthe Magento_Catalog module there's this block

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render" name="product.price.final">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="price_render" xsi:type="string">product.price.render.default</argument>
        <argument name="price_type_code" xsi:type="string">final_price</argument>
        <argument name="zone" xsi:type="string">item_view</argument>
    </arguments>
</block>
```

I have a catalog_product_view.xml in my own theme's layout folder, which is adding some additional blocks and moving or removing some others.

Now what I need to do is to add more arguments to the price block, but without changing anything else. So no moving, now changing of the original arguments etc.

Just adding for example:

```
<argument name="some_param" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
<argument name="another_param" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
```

How do I do that? What do I need to put in my layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to do it like this now:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.price.final">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="some_param" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
        <argument name="another_param" xsi:type="boolean">false</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

this just seems to be merged in, which is exactly what I need.